# Upgrading hard drive on exchange server

Tags: hard-drive, exchange-2003, migration

I have a Windows SBS (2003 R2) which is currently running Exchange 2003. It's now beginning to max out it's 25GB HDD and I have been given the job of upgrading it to a larger one (lucky me...).

Since the servers job is to host Exchange and a couple of very small/low traffic sites I am probably going to look at a [Western Digital](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/internal/desktop/) (Blue or Green) as the new HDD. I have read a lot of good things about them in terms of reliability/warrantys etc. (feel free to recommend any others).

My actual question is what is the best strategy for going about migrating Exchange over? I don't have any previous experience with this so I am assuming it goes along the lines of:

1. Install Exchange onto new HDD
2. Export existing Exchange database
3. Import database into new Exchange server
4. Decommission old HDD

I *hope* it's pretty much as straightforward as that, however, given that it's Exchange server I won't hold me breath...

Comment: A a minimum consider the WDC Red drives, as they're meant to be used in RAID configurations. That "meant for RAID" is mostly important in the case of failure; it's the difference between a crashing server and *just* a failed drive.

Comment: @ChrisS from speaking to other people I don't think those particular drives are the correct ones I should be looking at. I think I need to look at [enterprise-class](http://wdc.com/en/products/internal/enterprise) ones instead.

Comment: Well the XE and RE drives would be preferred over the Red drives; but the Blue and Green that you mentioned in your Question don't have TLER, which is vital to graceful failure.

Comment: @ChrisS I think I would need to look at the XE/RE ones and avoid the Green/Blue completely as they aren't enterprise specific ones. I assume the server won't have a SAS controller so I would need to go with SATA.

Comment: The XE drives are SAS only. The RE have some of each. Red are SATA only... I'm not sure what point you're trying to make though. What particular "enterprise" features are you looking for?

Comment: @ChrisS Well if I don't have an SAS controller then I would be limited to SATA (Red or RE). I am just looking for a hard-drive which is going to have longevity really and a good warranty policy, those ones seem to fit the bill. I was advised in the answers to go for more enterprise specific HDDs which is why I am eliminating the Green/Blue as they are designed for desktop usage not server.

Comment: All the WDC drives have roughly the same longevity in my experience. The only big differences are the speed and features (which determine price). Green are slow, cool, and cheap. Blue are medium all around. Black are fast-ish. Red are Blues with TLER for RAID use. RE have extended reporting and TLER, but are otherwise Blacks. They have 2.5" drives in Green, Blue and Black; and Raptors which are very fast. RE-SAS are Black drives with SAS controllers. XE are Raptors with SAS controllers. Also, there's AV drives with longer life bearings, supposedly. Different caching strategies as well.

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring for one minute the issue of running Exchange on desktop-class rather than enterprise class hardware...

I would look into using a disk cloning solution that can expand the volumes during the clone.  That way, your existing configuration is unchanged and the process will take much less time that a fresh install of Exchange and a migration of the data and settings.

There are plenty of both paid-for and free options available alhtough not all will support growing the volumes during the clone.  The Ultimate boot CD contains a number of options as a starting point and can be downloaded from http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

Comment: thanks for the response. How would I differentiate "*desktop-class*" hardware from enterprise-class? I don't have the spec of the machine in front of me so I can't give all the details, however, I seem to have said something that has made everyone think otherwise? Is it the choice of HDD? Like I mentioned in a comment in the other answer, I didn't purchase the server, however, it was bought for server specific reasons by someone who *apparently* does this for a living so I can only assume it *is* a proper server.

Comment: The Western Digital enterprise range can be found at http://www.wdc.com/en/products/internal/enterprise/

Comment: I've used Clonezilla with much success http://clonezilla.org/

Answer (score 3):

Given the target audience of this site, no one here will agree with your recommendation of running Exchange on a desktop-class computer with desktop-class storage.

Get a real server with real enterprise grade storage.

Here's a generic list of reasons you want a real server for server-type workloads:

- **ECC memory**: No silent corruption of important data before being committed to disk.
- **Dual power supplies**: Resilience against power supply failure and branch circuit failure (if you use two different circuits).
- **Hot-swap RAID**: replace failed drives, upgrade existing drives, or add new drives without shutting down the server.
- **Better MTBF**: the components in a server are designed to last longer than desktop computers because they rated for continuous operation. Desktop computer component MTBFs are usually rated based on 40-80 hours a week.

Comment: Don't really see what your getting at here? The machine is more than capable of doing the job it was bought to do....it has done so for the past 2 years. The HDD is now at max capacity and I need to upgrade it. I don't need *enterprise grade* storage, this is a small office which runs at max 3 people. Also, this is **not** an answer to my question, please delete and make it a comment.

Comment: Well, assuming it was not some "it challenged" Person buying SBS 2003 R2 after 2008... that machine is OLD. This means, it WILL fail. Replacing it after 5-6 years is what most sensible companies do.

Comment: @TomTom Just to be clear, I didn't purchase the server and I agree SBS 2003 is old. However, it hasn't *failed* for the past 2 years and the strain/demand from the server is most likely **not** going to change so I don't understand why your adament it *will* fail? Obviously hardware in general will hit EOF at some point, however, there is no immediate reason to go out and spend money a new server when it's not needed.

Comment: I am not saying you bought it. I just Point out some (not smart People) may hahve purchased that in 2008 or 2009, so it may not be that old. If it is as old as the Version, it WILL fail. THere is a lifetime Limit on elements like Motherboard. Larger (and some smaller companeis) thus run regular replacement cycle. FOr example my Business will replace ALL (except some Special newer) Desktops this year, and we also replace all our core Servers which still are quad core machines. Not that tey fail, it just is cheaper (we Need more capacity anyway) and... well, I can PLAN when we do that.

Comment: @TomTom I see your point. The server itself was bought in 2010 so it's relatively new hence why I am saying there is not much point in replacing it. Actually, AFAIK it was spec'd by an IT consultant who works for a company who specialise in enterprise backups etc which I am shocked about considering it *is* running 2003 & only had a 25GB HDD, especially considering he knew what the purpose of the server was for. The only reason I can think of would be budget limitations as the company was only just starting up back then.

Comment: @James Agree. I Thought it is older - a 25gb hard disc is - ah -- highly unusual. Is it a 15k SAS? I wonder what they bought there ;). Want to give it a HUGH boost? Get a 120gb SSD ;) Will make it fly ;)

Comment: This is exactly the reason you should get a Real Server now. If you have a real server, you could 1) pop out one of the mirrored drives and insert a bigger one, 2) wait for it to resync, 3) replace the other mirrored drive, 4) wait for it to resync, and 5) grow the volume. Don't extend past mistakes; plan for the future!

Comment: @TomTom I would be hesitant to look at SSDs for this as I have read their lifetime is relatively shorter compared to standard HDDs (albeit lightning fast, I have one on my home computer). Longneck - you keep mentioning *real server*, could you be more specific? The machine that's there I assume is good enough for what it needs to do. I would actually like to look at a RAID setup considering there is nothing there at the moment, I could do that *without* upgrading the actual server itself could I not?

Comment: See my edit for some examples. While you could get RAID set up in your desktop computer, I still won't recommend it. Low-end RAID controllers are notoriously unreliable, especially when a drive fails. If you want the protection of RAID, then do it with products known to work well and that are designed to handle failure gracefully: enterprise grade RAID controllers.

Comment: @longneck thanks for the advice. I don't have the spec of the machine in front of me right now, but I would *hope* that it is a proper server given it was bought for the purpose of being one! If that is the case, is a HDD upgrade all I need here? I would make sure I bought a server specific HDD...

Comment: Yes, but you REALLY should look at SSD. Expecially older Exchange is a little an IOPS hog. SSD are 150 time as fast as high end hdd These days. And not that expensive. I use quite a lot of the mby now in various functionalities (also as tansparent Cache) and tehy ROCK. And their shorter lifetime is hogwash. They last for years longer than the warranty when OVERWRITING THEM TOTALLY 10 TIMES PER DAY (which you do not do). Look at the NUMBERS - that is all academic.

Comment: I think we've pretty clearly established that while your "server" may have been spec'd and installed by a "professional", the evidence presented here shows otherwise. Forget about upgrading this drive and start thinking about a proper solution.

Comment: I'd agree about the benefits of SSDs however if cost is an issue and there are no current performance issues (the server might only be handling a few emails a day!!) then an enterprise HDD is a perfectly acceptable solution.  Of course best practice is to have it in at least a RAID1 array but thats a separate issue...

Comment: @TomTom cool thanks for the info on the SSDs, will defo look into them then if the lifetime isn't as unreliable as I have read. longneck - sorry to be persistent on this as I may well be wrong, but what *evidence* are you referring to which makes you think this isn't a proper server? I haven't given any spec other than the fact it had a 25GB HDD (which I also haven't given any spec on in terms of make/model etc). Perhaps the HDD I have referred to buying is thrown you off as it's **not** a server specific one, that's probably just a mistake on my part though.

Comment: He has the same Problem like me - I would simply said assume someone took old Hardware because I am really not Aware of any 2010 timeframe 25gb hard disc, outside of 15k SAS (and even then it would be a Little old). If you would say "25gb SSD" I Would agree, but I simply am not Aware of any hard disc that small. Not 2010.

Comment: @Phil Just to pick up on that - the email load is not really that high, I would say roughly 100 emails a day max. In terms of performance, it's coped perfectly fine for the past 2 years there has never been any complaints about it so I think an enterprise HDD would be fine, however, if I could get an SSD (at least big enough storage) for relatively cheap I would possibly opt for that. I definitely want to get a RAID1 setup going on as there is nothing on the server at the moment for automatic backups, are there only specific HDDs which allow RAID?

Comment: All do RAID. Not sure what you go for - I am retiring some of 120gb SSD now (moving to 512). The good Thing with SSD is they use less power, get less hot and fail mostly "good" (no more writes, but reading still works). The Price difference is a joke in your size range, once you take in the Price of actually replacing things. Sadly Windows has no proper hybrid RAID Support (one ssd with one hard disc, all reads to the SSD Only).

Comment: OK, so let's assume you have a good server. Someone stuck a POS old, small hard drive in it. That still causes me to question the motives and skillset of the person who set it up. You're seeing the tip of the iceberg: the drive is full. You should investigate the entire system, top to bottom.

Comment: Pracitally, though, a small Server like that should be virtual These days.

Comment: @longneck I definitely share your concerns, I will get the full spec of the server and post it when I get a chance. Any part in particular you would be interested in? TomTom I agree, I have actually suggested looking at virtual/cloud hosting and getting rid of the headache of server maintenance completely, however, I think their trying to keep expenditure to a minimum. The way they see it they have a server which needs more space so they want to upgrade it. My initial thought was a simple RAID setup would be all that's needed here, but after this discussion I am beginning to think not...

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if there is room in the server, is simpliy to ADD, not replace the existing HDD.  Add the new disk (or disks, if you can add RAID when you didn't before) and format the drive, then simply use the tools available to move the Exchange data store.  This link has detailed instructions on how to do so: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708031(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this on a desktop, so it seems to work:

It may be possible to "move" the server without actually needing to reinstall anything at all.

1. Install your second hard drive in your server.
2. Set your main hard drive as a dynamic disk in the "Disk Management" pane of the computer management administrative tool.
3. Add the new hard drive as a mirror of the old hard drive.
4. Wait for drives to synchronize.
5. Break the mirror by removing the old drive.
6. Expand the partition to take up the full size of the new hard-drive.

It let me move my desktop from a hard drive that was having SMART errors without any trouble, so it should work for you too.

Comment: I like the idea of this approach....it would be ideal if I didn't need to re-install anything. I have never mirrored a drive before I assume it migrates *everything* including the OS?